# oracle outer join query

Tags: oracle9i

I have 3 oracle tables. A joins to B and B joins to C. I want all records from A irerspective of whether a corresponding record exists in B or C. I wrote a query like this:

```
select a.name from a,b,c where a.a_id = b.b_id(+) and b.b_id = c.c_id(+)
```

This query does not seem right to me, particularly with the second join. What will exactly happen if there is a record in A but correspondingly nothing in B and C? Will it still fetch the record?

For some reason the above query returns same count of records as `select a.name from a`
So I am guessing that the query is right? Also is there a better way to rewrite the query?

Comment: The a rows will be returned regardless whether there is any row with matching id in b or c. Now what happens if for id 1 there is an a row, a c row and no b row? b.b_id is null...so...try it.

Comment: Thank you. If for id 1 in a, there is no b row, then how there will be a c row? c has no direct relationship with a? Can you please explain little bit?

Comment: You got it. Since there's no b row, b.b_id is null, even if a c row exists you won't retrieve it. Consider that when you are writing this kind of join.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the better query can be

```
Select a.name from A a left join B b on a.a_id=b.b_id inner join C c on b.b_id=c.c_id
```

This should give the result as you have expected

http://rajanmaharjan.com.np